# first element in form can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this problem

```
.container.weekdays
  .row
   .col-sm-3  
      .panel-default data-day="#{@weekdays[0]}"
       .h3 
         |Today's menu.            
         =@weekdays[0]
        br
         =link_to "Today's menu", admin_menu_path("#{@weekdays[0]}"),   class: 'today', remote: true
      hr
      hr
    fieldset
      legend Update menu here
      =form_for [:admin, @menu] ,method: :patch, remote: true do |f|
        p
          = f.select(:type, options_for_select(["", :First, :Second, :Drink], include_blank: true))
        p
          =f.label 'Name'
          =f.text_field :name
        p
          =f.label 'Price'
          =f.number_field :price              
        = f.submit
```

and menus controller, where show action is working right

```
class Admin::MenusController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_menu , only:[:update]
  def show  
    @menu = Menu.where(day: params[:id])  
  end

  def update 
    @menu = Menu.where(day: DateTime.now.strftime("%A"))       
    @item = menu_params.type.constantize.new(name: menu_parms.name, price: params[:menu][:price], menu: @menu)
    @item.save
  end

  private  
  def menu_params
    params.require(:menu).permit(:type, :name, :price)
  end
end
```

I am recieving first argument cn't be nill in form update, need some help n that. I do undestand that code is awful but still I am a newcommer it should work first than I'll try to refact

To better understand the problem here is menu model

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dishes

  delegate :firstmeals, :secondmeals, :drinks, to: :dishes

  validates :day, presence: true
  validates :day, uniqueness: true

  def self.get_menu day
    Menu.where(day: day).first
  end 

  private
  def to_param
    day
  end
```

end

So I do not actually need to update menu, I need only to create a dish. But the same problemm still exist

```
  fieldset
      legend Update menu here
      =form_for [:admin, @dish], method: :patch, remote: true do |f|
        p
          = f.select(:type, options_for_select(["", :First, :Second, :Drink], include_blank: true))
        p
          =f.label 'Name'
          =f.text_field :name
        p
          =f.label 'Price'
          =f.number_field :price              
        = f.submit
```

Comment: Where is your `new` action? Inside this action you need to do `@menu = Menu.new`. Currently `@menu` is `nil`.

Comment: Actually I do not need to create menu, they are created once (7 menus ) and then are only updated

Comment: So that form is to update?

Comment: I've typed some explanations and corrections

Answer (score 2):

`include_blank` should be outside of `options_for_select`

```
= f.select(:type, options_for_select([:First, :Second, :Drink]), { include_blank: true })
```

If you are passing `include_blank` option you don't need to add empty string manually

documentation for [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: The error OP said is not from "select" list though.